# Determining covariance - Probability Homework

Tags: probability

I know this is a simple question, but I am having problems with it. Given that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed random variables such that: $$Y|X=x \in Bin(n,x) \; and \; X \in U(0,1) \;,$$ I have found $$E[Y]= \frac{n}{2} \; and \; VarY=\frac{n^2}{12}+\frac{n}{6}\;.$$ Now I am asked to find the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, $cov(X,Y)$. However, there is a restriction that says I am not allowed to use techniques from the Bayesian section of the chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to solve this is to *realize* $Y$ and $X$ on the same probability space. For example, consider $n$ random variables $X_k$, i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$, and independent of $X$. Then,
$$
Y=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb 1_{X_k\leqslant X}
$$
has the required conditional distribution (can you check this?). Furthermore,
$$
\mathbb E(X\mathbb 1_{X_k\leqslant X})=\iint_{[0,1]^2}x\mathbb 1_{y\leqslant x}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx=\int_0^1x^2\mathrm dx=\tfrac13.
$$
Can you complete the computation of $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)$ from here?

**Edit:** To explain why such a realization of $Y$ is suitable, recall that, for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, a random variable with binomial $(n,x)$ distribution is
$$
Y_x=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb 1_{X_k\leqslant x}.
$$

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't make much sense to me. I haven't seen these notations before i.e. $\mathbb E(X\mathbb 1_{X_k\leqslant X})$

Comment: $\mathbf 1_A$ is $1$ when $A$ is true and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: No, I can't solve from here

Comment: Did you check the conditional distribution?

Comment: No, I can't understand how you got $Y$. To get $P(Y=k)$ I would solve $\int_o^1P(Y=k|X=x)f_X(x)dx$

Comment: *how you got Y*. See Edit. *To get P(Y=k) I would solve ∫01P(Y=k|X=x)fX(x)dx*. Right.

Comment: So, if $\mathbb E(X\mathbb 1_{X_k\leqslant X})=E(XY)$ Then $cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$ correct?

Comment: The two assertions are unrelated, the first one is false in the context (since Y is a sum), the second one is always true (by definition).